# html containers background issue

Tags: css, html, background, background-color

I have problem when I try to set a background to `.header` - nothing changes, please help, I am so confused.

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='header'>
        <div class='logo'></div>
        <div class='search'>
            <form class="search" method='post'>
                <input type='text' name='text'>
                <input type='submit' value='search'>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class='utility'></div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- excuse me i forgot to type </div> here in the post -->
```

**CSS file**

```
html {
    background: #62B0FF;
}

body {  
    text-align:left;
    font: 13px /1.5 arial,helvetica,tahoma;
    color: black;
}

/* i wanted to put 120px free space
   to see background
   but nothing is there */

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.header {     
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: black;
}

.logo {     
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
}

.search {    
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 620px;
}

.utility {
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: try setting  .header {
             background-color: red;
             display: block;
          }

Comment: if there is any other CSS at play for the other elements, you should post it. it could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to `.header`. If you are floating any child elements (`input`, `.logo`, `.search` etc) and then not clearing them, the `.header` element will not expand to fit the content.

So, the chances are that the background of the `.header` element is `red`, but you just cannot see it.

See these examples:

*Float, no clear - shows the behaviour you are describing*

**http://jsfiddle.net/qrS3u/**

*Float, with clear - background is red*

**http://jsfiddle.net/qrS3u/1/**

**Edit**

**For more information about why this happens with floating elements and how to fix them, check out [this CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)**

Comment: yeah man that worked!,you are my HERO,can you clearly explain what happened!!!what got hide by the overflow,i even put 120px free space between logo and utility to see the red background but i failed,thanks

Comment: @user1182612 Excellent, glad it worked. I have added a link to my answer which explains the how and why of clearing floats. The `overflow: hidden` doesn't actually hide anything, it it just another way of clearing the floats. Don't forget to mark this as your accepted answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you are just missing `</div>` . otherwise  its just working fine.

**check the Fiddle Example :** http://jsfiddle.net/Znw7P/

Comment: Also works just fine without the missing closing div: http://jsfiddle.net/Znw7P/1/

Comment: yeah might be.. but that's not good right..it may create some issues in someplaces.

Comment: I agree, it should be fixed - I just meant it is not the solution to this problem. The asker hasn't really given us enough information to answer their question accurately.

Comment: excuse me i forgot to type </div> here in the post

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing div ( "`</div>`" ) tag. That could be a factor.

Also, you need to wrap the CSS code in `<style>` tags. Instead of the last three lines, use this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .header {
             background-color: red;
               }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your CSS from this:

```
.header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to this:

```
.header {
    background: red;
}
```